# Buying motor-vehicle from another country

Tags: european-union, motor-vehicle

I'm looking to buy a motorcycle from another country in the EU and bring it back. The motorcycle will be purchased as second hand. For this, there is normally a purchase declaration (a small contract that specifies e characteristics of the product, the seller and the buyer).

My question is in what language should the purchase declaration be written in when both countries speak different languages?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but worth knowing: Even if you import a vehicle within the EU, the paperwork may not be trivial. As far as I know, you will need "certificates of conformity" and similar which can be difficult. Before buying, I recommend to make sure you are aware of all the documents needed for registering in the target country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Doesn’t matter

Ideally though, a language both parties understand, or if that is not possible, the contract in one language should be accompanied by a certified translation.